# how to generate structure file from blast results of an input sequence

Tags: python, blast, pdb, nucleotide-models

I have tried to incorporate blast in my application using biopython.i could extract the blast results but now i want to extract the structure file corresponding matches. My code is :

```
from Bio.SeqIO import parse 
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord 
from Bio.Seq import Seq 

file = open("prats.fasta") 

records = parse(file,"fasta") 
for record in records:   
    print("Id: %s" % record.id) 
    print("Name: %s" % record.name) 
    print("Description: %s" % record.description) 
    print("Annotations: %s" % record.annotations) 
    print("Sequence Data: %s" % record.seq) 
    print("Sequence Alphabet: %s" % record.seq.alphabet)

from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
sequence_data = open("prats.fasta").read() 
sequence_data 

result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", sequence_data) 
result_handle

with open('results.xml', 'w') as save_file:
    blast_results = result_handle.read()
    print(blast_results)
    save_file.write(blast_results)

from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
E_VALUE_THRESH = 1e-20 
for record in NCBIXML.parse(open("results.xml")): 
    if record.alignments: 
        print("\n") 
        print("query: %s" % record.query[:100]) 
        for align in record.alignments: 
            for hsp in align.hsps: 
                if hsp.expect < E_VALUE_THRESH: 
                    print("match: %s " % align.title[:100])
```

from here i want to generate the xml files and then fetch structure of each nucleotides results

Answer (score 1):

### If you the DNA/RNA crystal structure:

Simply change the `nt` in `NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", sequence_data)` to `pdbnt` to get the nucleotide sequence in a chain.
The PDB code will be the accession ID with an underscore plus chain letter.
Do note that the PDB structure may be offset.

### If you want the crystal structures of the encoded protein:

`blastx` (translation) on the `pdbaa` database. As above the PDB code will be as above.

### If you want a model of the encoded protein:

Check Swissmodel for a pre-existing close threaded model, else check out I-Tasser (best), Phyre (fast).

### If you want a model of the DNA/RNA:

You are running blast without special settings —its not a short motif—, so these things may be long, so do be weary of any result. There are a few RNA folding prediction tools online (e.g. RNAFold).